# setState inside a method one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m working on a React project, which involves displaying a value (DisplayValue) and then storing that value inside state so that I can use it later. Problem is state is always one step behind (for instance, if displayValue is "12", value is just 1). I need both values to be the same. Is it because setState is async? How can I fix it?

```
inputDigit(digit) {
    const {
        pendingOperation,
        displayValue
    } = this.state;

    if (pendingOperation) {
        this.setState({
            displayValue: String(digit),
            pendingOperation: false
        })
    }
    value1 = parseFloat(displayValue);
    this.setState({
        displayValue: displayValue === "0" ? String(digit) : displayValue + String(digit),
        value: value1
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.value)
    })
};
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/HernanF/pen/jXzPJp

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format your code with consistent and standard indentation and such, so it's easy for people to read and help you. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: If you `console.log()` state right after a `this.setState()` call, the log will show the previous state, yes. There's no need to fix anything though.

Comment: @ChrisG - It's in the state update completion callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not in the codepen

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn´t clear enough in the question. I need both values to be the same (value should ALWAYS match displayValue)

Comment: Why do you need that `displayValue==="0" ? String(digit)`?

Comment: Alright, I see that the issue is, and it has nothing to do with state or async. You are setting `displayValue` to a new value based on user input, and at the same time you're setting `value` to the **old** `displayValue`. Why would you expect them to be the same if you deliberately assign a new and an old value to them?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He's doing it in the question though, too, as far as I can see

Comment: @ChrisG - The only `console.log` in the question is in the state change completion callback function passed as the second argument to `setState`. It's fine there, that callback isn't executed until the state change has been made.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, I'm referring to setting `value` to the previous `displayValue`, which turns out is the actual issue. (see my 3rd comment)

Comment: @ChrisG - Ahhhh, I see why we're talking past each other. :-) I read your first comment as "If you do what you're doing (`console.log()` state right after a `this.setState()`), the log will show the previous state." But you mean "If you add a `console.log` after..." I get what you're saying now. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, the codepen had `log()` calls after the `setState`, not in its callback. But anyway, this issue isn't about react or setstate or any of that. See Bsalex's answer and OP's comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

You're breaking [a fundamental React rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): Never set state based on existing state by passing an object into `setState`. Instead, use the callback form, and use the state object the callback form receives. You also probably want to call `setState` **once**, not (potentially) twice.

So, you want those changes in the update callback, *something* like this:

```
inputDigit(digit) {
    this.setState(
        ({pendingOperation, displayValue}) => {
            const newState = {};
            if (pendingOperation) {
                newState.displayValue = String(digit);
                newState.pendingOperation = false;
            }
            newState.value = parseFloat(displayValue);
            // Not sure what you're trying to do with the second setState calls' `displayValue: displayValue === "0" ? String(digit) : displayValue + String(digit),`...
            return newState;
        },
        () => {
            console.log(this.state.value)
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a problem in the code, not React

```
value1 = parseFloat(displayValue);
```

should be

```
value1 = parseFloat(displayValue + String(digit));
```

The same as for `displayValue`

Comment: Thank for the reply. Why doesn´t my approach work though? Shouldn´t value1 get set to the same value as displayValue?

Comment: @newToProgramming Variable assignments don't magically extend into the future. You are setting `value1` to `displayValue`, then you *change* `displayValue`, then you assign `value1` (i.e. the old displayValue) to `value`.